# Importance Sampling of a Student-t with mean 0, $\sigma^2$ and degrees of freedom unknown

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, t-distribution, importance-sampling

I want to calculate the posterior parameters of a Student-t by importance sampling. In order to tune the importance density I sample from the prior first. My data is demeaned, the degrees of freedom ($v$) are about 4 and the standard deviation ($\sigma^2$) about 0.7. I use the latent variable representation of the Student-t, i.e.

$Y_i \sim t_v(0, \sigma^2) \rightarrow Y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2/\omega_i) \text{ and } \omega_i \sim \mathcal{G}(v/2, v/2)$

I use a truncated Gamma as a prior for $v$ and a Inverse Gamma for $\sigma^2$.

As a first step I sample from the prior of $v$ and $\sigma^2$ and 'weight' these draws by the likelihood of the data ($p(Y|\sigma^2, \omega)$) and the likelihood of the $\omega$s ($p(\omega|v)$). The problem is, the likelihood of the $\omega$s 'prefers' higher $v$s, leading to a significant weight on these draws.

As a result I get an expected value of about 20 for $v$, even though this value is at the end of the (prior) distribution. The draws of such values receive so much more weight, that the other draws are more or less irrelevant. I have checked the log-likelihoods of both parts (the data and $\omega$). The data is 'indifferent' (with respect to $v$), while $\omega$ is not.

I also tried to use simulated data, my sampler always leads to very high values for $v$. I have checked the computation of the log-likelihoods, I did it right (assuming that the functions of R are correct, which should be definitely the case). Does anyone have an idea what I could have made wrong?

Since I use the results of this first step in order to tune the importance density, importance sampling leads to even higher values for $v$, about 400.

Short update:
Obviously it works if I use the log-likelihood Student-t directly. Of course, this is the more straightforward approach. But I'm still wondering why the other approach doesn't work. Any ideas?